# Added a Content-Security-Policy to Node.js/Express.js server code, then removed it, but Google Chrome is still blocking content

Tags: node.js, express, content-security-policy

**NOTICE**: Revised issue down below at the EDIT section.

I've been learning about Content-Security-Policies in an attempt to learn various security concepts, because I am building a website from scratch. I realize it may not be a huge deal since I won't be receiving any user input, however I want to learn these concepts and begin to apply them to keep my site from being vulnerable to things like Javascript injection.

In my `server.js` file, I serve my pages via Express in the following code:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/views/home.html"));
});
```

To add the Content-Security-Policy (CSP) to my server code, I added the following code ***before*** the above code, and before using Express to serve static files:

```
//the following code is called right after the creation of the express server

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com");
    return next();
});

//static css/js/img files served here:
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//then the app.get method I defined above
```

I restarted my node server, opened up chrome, went to http://localhost:8080 where I have my node website listening, and as expected, my home page wasn't loading the various external scripts, CDNs, and external styles I have in my project.

After seeing that the CSP worked, I decided to remove the entire `app.use` function that set the CSP so I could create my list of directives so I could add the CSP later.

I removed that code block, saved, restarted the node server, and when I opened up Google Chrome, I was still getting notices under the security tab in the Chrome Dev Tools saying that all of my external content was being blocked due a violation of `"default-src 'self'"` or the `"script-src 'self'"` directives - again, this is ***after*** I removed the CSP code above from my server file. However, when I opened up my application in Safari, everything loaded fine. Why is Chrome still blocking content even though I removed the code to set a CSP in the HTTP headers in my server code?

EDIT: I ended up reseting my Chrome settings which fixed the issue. However, I'm unsure of which setting to go to in Chrome now, rather than resetting all settings. Also obviously the CSP only applied to the home page in that instance, I would need to set the CSP within each html page's GET method, yes?